# How to import elements from an external java library to AnyLogic workspace (palette)?

Tags: java, anylogic

In eclipse we can import the elements of a jar file to palette and use them in designing GUI. I was wondering if we can do the same thing in AnyLogic?

I have added a java library (JCalendar for example) to the dependencies of my model. I tried to add it as a library object class using the "Manage Libraries" option in the palette view. When I add the Jar file it gives me this error:

Error while opening the library:
Invalid library format. Library description is missing.

Is there a way to fix this error?
If not, how can I use the external library elements in my model? How to know which element of the controls palette to use to pick up the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AnyLogic libraries can only be libraries you created with AnyLogic.

In your case, create a new model and empty agent class. Drag a JCalendar instance into the new agent class.

Then, you can turn it into an AnyLogic library as below:
[image]

In your real models, you can now add the library through "manage libraries" and drag and drop your object.

Do check the help on this as well, you can do some neat tricks with your own libraries.

Comment: So pure Java coding is the only way to use external libraries.
Moreover, it seems like JCalendar can be only created as independent individual window of the model. So it cannot be added at model canvas since the model presentation is drawn with HTML5, not with Java. Therefor it will not work in AnyLogic Cloud either.

I hope you write to us about these neat tricks with custom libraries in your blog! Thank you Benjamin.

Comment: maybe check for a different library than JCalendar that can show in html5? Would be great to share with the community if you find a solution as it is such a common thing ...